# SQL: Condensing individual rating tables into one for IMDb personal project

Tags: sql, ms-access, imdb

I'm currently working on a personal project and I could use a little help.

Scenario:

I'm creating a database (MS Access) for all of the movies myself and some friends have ever watched. We rated all of our movies on IMDb and used the export feature to get all of the movie data and our movie ratings. I plan on doing some summary analysis on Excel. My experience with SQL and relational databases is minor, but I really enjoy it and this project is helping me to understand it all better.

Problem:

Here's what my table looks like that stores all of the movie information (`const` is used as the primary key.): 
[image]

Then for each individual rater I have a separate table with `const`, and `[You rated]` as the columns, as shown here with James' ratings:

[image: http://imgur.com/StTd1QO]

**I want to take all of the individual tables for the ratings and condense them into one table** with the columns: `rater` (i.e. James, Alex, Doug), `const`, and `yourRate`. How would I go about this?

Comment: If you must have a table as the result: 1) Write the union query described in my prior answer and then 2) write a make-table query that uses the union as an input and creates the table you want.  Other wise, I think the union gives you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you named the individual tables holding the ratings in a consistent manner the easiest way to do this is to use a vba-function to extract the data from the different tables and insert it into a new table.

For example, if you have a new table `ratings (rater, const, yourrating)` and want to insert ratings from tables named like `R_JAMES` this code will do that:

```
Function InsertRatings()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT name FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0 AND Name like 'R[_]J%';"
    rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        strSql = "INSERT INTO ratings SELECT '" + rs!Name + "' AS Rater, const, [you rated] as yourrate from " + rs!Name + ";"

        DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Function
```

Add this as a visual basic module and run it after adjusting the column names if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union query something like

```
select "rater 1" as rater, const, [you rated] from [rater 1]
union select "rater 2", const, [you rated] from [rater 2]
...
union select "rater n", const, [you rated] from [rater n]
```

This won't make a new table, but the query can be used as if it were a table for most purposes.

To make a Union query, open a new query in design view, don't select any tables to put in it, then look at is in SQL view.  Put in the code above, 1 line per rater that you need to include.

Comment: If you must have a table as the result: